# EXTJS 3 API to convert datetime

Tags: javascript, extjs

In the EXTJS 3, if I have a string like 'Fri Jul 13 00:00:00 EDT 2012' , how can I get date string '07/13/2012' ? Does EXTJS have some API to handle this ?

Thanks

---- Update ---
I found a way, like this

```
               if (Ext.isDate("Fri Jul 13 00:00:00 EDT 2012")) {
                    var date1 = new Date("Fri Jul 13 00:00:00 EDT 2012");
                    var start_str = date1.format('m/d/Y');
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about ExtJS specifically but there's a very similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259013/extjs-datefield-using-different-display-format) and the answer links to [the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Date); it's worth checking that question out just for the example in the answer though!

In a pure Javascript implementation a regex may be the way to go. There's quite a few [Regex Examples](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev3.shtml) available and even a few [Generators](http://txt2re.com/) which can make your life easier if you aren't too confident with regex. Here's an example of the generated code from that site - [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/5wZak/). (*Thats not the cleanest way of doing a regex, when you use a generator it actually leaves quite a lot to be desired unfortunately. **But it does work and give a decent starting point!***)

Upon closer inspection of the string, I notice it uses text to signify the month. This could be worked around via the use of an [enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287903/enums-in-javascript).

**As far as ExtJS goes - there's a pretty good blog post [here](http://aboutfrontend.com/extjs/extjs-date-format-demystified/) about some of the date format options. But I think the documentation linked at the top of the answer is the best place to be looking.**

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object should provide everything you need here:

```
var d = new Date('Fri Jul 13 00:00:00 EDT 2012');
var out = (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear()
```